# Upgrading from Spring 3.0 to Spring 4.0 breaking customArgumentResolvers in ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-3

We have upgraded our system from Spring 3.0 to Spring 3.2 , mostly things are working well but recently we've faced one and very challenging issue and that is with `CustomWebArgumentResolver` property defined within Bean and also I've debugged the code , figured out that control never enters in method resolveArgument and supportsParameter defined in `CPathResolver` class

Below is the bean created in configuration file `webmvc-config.xml` :

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver">
       <property name="customArgumentResolvers">
           <list>
               <bean class="com.mmt.web.resolver.CPathResolver"/>
           </list>
           </property>
</bean>
```

And CPathResolver.java

```
    public class CPathResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

        @Override
            public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
            CPathVariable pathParamAnnotation = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(CPathVariable.class);
            if(pathParamAnnotation==null) return false;

            return true;
            }

        @Override
            public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                    NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory)
                    throws Exception {
            CPathVariable pathParamAnnotation = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(CPathVariable.class);
            if(pathParamAnnotation !=null) {
                String pathValue = pathParamAnnotation.value();
                if(StringUtils.hasText(pathValue)){
                    if(pathValue.equals("pos"))return "site";
                }
            }

            return null;
            }

    }
```

And CPathVariable is defined as :

```
    @Target( { ElementType.PARAMETER })

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

    @Documented

    public @interface CPathVariable {

        String value() default "";

    }
```

In my controller named HTLReviewController , I am trying to `throw exception` in `try catch block` in `@RequestMapping` method and handling the exception via `@ExceptionHanler` annotation in the same controller .

```
    @Controller
    class HTLReviewController {

            @RequestMapping(value = "/review", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String review(Model model, @PathVariable(POS_VARIABLE) String pos,
                    String searchCountryCode,
                    String searchCityCode)throws MTException {

               /*
                some code
               */
              try{

              }

            catch(Exception e){
               new  MTException(0,
                            "Error while getting details for abc : "
                                    + selectedHotelId, e);

           }

        @ExceptionHandler(MTException.class)

        public ModelAndView handleMTException(MTException ex,HttpServletRequest       request,@CPathVariable(POS_VARIABLE) String pos
                    ) {

              /*
               some code
               */

        }  
    }
```

`I am getting below exception`

```
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method:
public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.mmt.hotels.web.controllers.HTLReviewController.handleMTException(com.test.web.exceptions.MTException
,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String)|java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable resolver for argument [2] [type=java.lang.String]|
```

Please folks give me your valuable suggestions to resolve this issue .